# Что означает оператор |= в декомпилированном коде?

Tags: c#

Некий код из рефлектора

```
byte[] expr_239_cp_0 = this.buf;
int expr_239_cp_1 = num;
expr_239_cp_0[expr_239_cp_1] |= 1;
```

Что за операция `|=1`?

Comment: выставление последнего бита числа в единицу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Оператор |=](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx) - выполняет операцию побитовое ИЛИ.

Запись

```
x |= 1
```

эквивалентна

```
x = x | 1
```

При использовании с параметром 1 - у числа стоящего слева, последний бит устанавливается в 1.

Так как это побитовая операция, то для нее опреранды являются наборами бит, это значит, что запись `100 | 192` будет выполнена в следующем виде

```
01100100
11000000
--------
11100100
```

И будет равна `228`.

Comment: Понял. Там встречается и такое:

    expr_101C_cp_0[expr_101C_cp_1] |= 192;

Разве можно выставить бит в 192?

Comment: @jshapen, это побитовая операция. то есть для нее операнды представляют собой набор бит

Comment: @jshapen, добавил в ответ пример